# Slur for same-pitch notes in chords: Tie or not?

Tags: piano, articulation, slurs

I encountered this in Mozart KV 310:
[image]

Should I repeat the `C` here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C should be repeated. In order to be considered a tie, the mark would have to begin at the first C and go directly to the second C. So in this case the mark is a slur.

Comment: Although not strictly part-writing, for the purpose of the tie could you consider the upper stave in that bar to have two different voices, neither of which repeat a note?

Comment: @gidds That's a reasonable way to think about it, and advantageous, too, for issues like voicing.

Answer (score 8):

Because the slur mark encompasses two notes (not just the C), then CE is played, followed by AC. A tie mark will always be starting and finishing at the same level, rather than slanting, as here. Simply because a tie will join two notes that are the same, but here, the mark is slanting, a good clue as to it being a slur.